# Using Google maps API with CloudMade maps

Tags: google-maps, licensing, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an iPhone app that uses a map and show direction between two points on the map, the problem is i cant use the Google maps because it does not support street naming in my country, so instead I'm using CloudMade maps. 
The question is can i still query Google servers with direction requests and use the results on the CloudMade map? Is the Google license allows it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's [terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) you cannot place any content obtained from Google's service on any other map without written permission from Google.

> 10.1.1
>   (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or
>   display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are
>   explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, or
>   through written permission from Google. For example, you must not use
>   geocodes obtained through the Service except in conjunction with a
>   Google map, but you may display Street View imagery without a
>   corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation
>   explicitly permits you to do so.

I would contact Google, they may be able to work with you in your situation.

**Update:**

Google contact information is a bit sparse for free maps.

Here is a link to the permissions tool:

http://www.google.com/intl/en/permissions/geoguidelines.html

This is a link to Google Enterprise support:

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/bin/answer.py?answer=142244#maps

Or you may want to try and contact a Google office in your country if one exists.  I do not believe their legal department has a direct contact information for the public.

http://www.google.com/intl/en/about/corporate/company/address.html

An here is the Google premier sales contact information.  I don't think you would need to obtain a premier license (they are expensive) with the information you provided about your app but the sales representative may be able to point you in the right direction.

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/bin/request.py?contact_type=gme&utm_campaign=en-codepremier

Comment: thanks! can you please give me an email to contact Google support for this subject? i didn't found it..